# Why won't COM2 work?

Tags: nvidia, serial-port

What is the command for turning COM2 (Header Connector) on. Motherboard is a Intel D2500HN with one DB9 (COM1) and a header connector for COM2. We were using the Intel D425KT and both COM ports worked fine.

Comment: There is no such thing as "turning COM2" on. What is your goal? Have you checked the baud rate, parity bits, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try minicom.

> minicom is a friendly serial communication program.   Features include
>   dialing directory with auto-redial, a separate script language
>   interpreter, capture to file, multiple users with individual
>   configurations, and more.

To install minicom, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `ls /dev/ttyS*` show? That command should show give you a list of the available serial ports. Also be sure that you have enabled the serial port in the bios.

To be able to access the serial port as a normal user you have to add that user to the `dialout` group. Issue the following command in a terminal: `sudo add user <username> dialout`

If you have other questions let us know.